# can not install Android System Webview on Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I have Galaxy S3 that is running Android 4.4.2.  I keep noticing that more and more apps do not display web stuff on my phone.  I suspect it is because I am missing Android System Webview.  The play store says that current version of webview in incompatible with my 4.4.2.
1) what is the minimum Android version that the webview supports?
2) are there any legit and solid alternatives to Google's webview that can be installed instead?

Answer (score 4):

From: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

Only starting with Android 5.0 was the System WebView updatable.

For anything below Android 5.0, apps could have included their own WebView like the [now deprecated](https://web.archive.org/web/20190305163504/https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/crosswalk-final-release.html) [Project Crosswalk](https://web.archive.org/web/20190223231824/https://crosswalk-project.org/) (repo [here](https://github.com/crosswalk-project)) to handle the differing levels of HTML5 support on older Android devices.

Another option would be [Mozilla's GeckoView](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView) which supports devices with Android 4.3 and up.

Given the Android framework level changes needed for an updatable WebView, your best bet is upgrade the OS on your device.