# How to use chrome DevTools for android webview api 19 below?

Tags: android, webview

So I'm trying to debug my webview which it doesn't load font's and some of the elements are distorted, and this only happens in android 4.4 and below and I want to debug it but unfortunately  WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
method only works in api 19 and above.
I think this is happening because the webview client in android 4.4 below is WebKit not chrome.
So what is the solution for this situation?

Comment: See: [Android: Remote webview debugging for API level below 19?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42495780/295004)

Comment: Already checked it, but that doesn't answer what I want.

Comment: Unfortunately your options for 4.4 and below are limited. Either you do manual logging or JavaScript tooling frameworks or if the feature doesn't exist you can include a [third party webview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50459892/295004) which has the features you need (at the cost of a larger APK).